# codeigniter form helper wiredness

Tags: codeigniter

I have some of wiredness going on in some code I am writing. I have a regular form to update a user account. The fields are populated with data from the database. after changing that needs to be changed, I can't submit the form. when I click on the button, it behaves like disabled submit with javascript but I didn't. On the otherhand if I use javascript and stop it from submitting and console log to see if a click is happening, it appears the button is being clicked but just nothing. below is my code in my view for the form.

```
form_open('members/users/update_curr_user');

$data5 = array('name'=>'username','id'=>'username','value'=>$uservar['username']);
echo 'Username  :'.form_input($data5);

$data6 = array('name'=>'email','id'=>'email','value'=>$uservar['email']);
echo 'Email Address :'.form_input($data6);

$phone1 = array('name'=>'phone','id'=>'phone','value'=>$uservar['phone']);
echo 'Your phone number formatted like so: 0802-331-5544'.form_input($phone1);

switch ($uservar['active']):
   case 0:
    $data7 = array(
        'name'=>'status',
        'id'=>  'status',
        'value' =>'Deactivated'
    );
    echo 'Status : Active or Deactivated'.form_input($data7);
    break;
 case 1:
    $data8 = array(
        'name' =>'status',
        'id'   =>'status',
        'value'=>'active'
    );
    echo 'Status :Active or Deactivated'.form_input($data8);
    break;
 endswitch;

 $group1 = array('name'=>'group','id'=>'group','value'=>$uservar['group']);
 echo 'Group :'.form_dropdown('group',$groups).'<br />'; 
 echo '<br /><br />';

//$data9 = 'id="updateuser"';
//echo form_submit('submit','Update User',$data9);
?>
<input name="submit" id="updateuser" type="submit" value="Update User" />
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

Because of how unsure I was of what was going on I manually created a button still the same. Other forms on the page are working ok. If it's of any consequence, I am using phil sturgeon's template library, ion_auth and firephp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually writing out the form tag.  You need to put an echo up there.  Do this:

```
 echo form_open('members/users/update_curr_user');
```

Your submit button should now work.

Comment: Joe, thanks I feel dumb but I guess these things happen to the best also right?! thanks :-)